# Drop down menu Validation on button press w/ Alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The user should select one of the options in the drop down menu before proceeding with the form. The "next button" should send an alert if no option is selected. Both Yes and No should allow the next button to work. I need a JavaScript for this.

Here is my HTML:

```html
<fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Past History </h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Please select one of the following</h3>
    <div>
        <select name="past" id="past">
            <option value=""disabled selected>Select One</option>
            <option value="a">Yes</option>
            <option value="b">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" id="nextpast" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works fine and won't let the user continue unless they have selected an option

```js
function alertBox() {
    if($("#past option:selected").text() == "Select One"){
        alert("You must select an option!");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
    <h2 class="fs-title">Past History </h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Please select one of the following</h3>
    <div>
        <select name="past" id="past">
            <option value=""disabled selected>Select One</option>
            <option value="a">Yes</option>
            <option value="b">No</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" onclick="alertBox()" name="next" id="next" class="next action-button" id="nextpast" value="Next" />
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using javascript, just add a listener for that button:

```
var $nextButton = document.getElementById('nextbutton');
$nextButton.addEventListener('click', nextButtonfunc);

var nextButtonfunc = function() {
var $dropDownPast = document.getElementById('past');
 if ($dropDownPast.value === '') alert('message')
}
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Does this allow the user to move on if they have not selected yes or no?

Comment: No, but you can add it, in nextButtonFunc you have te context information of event click button, and then you can make to not continue if you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
 document.querySelector("input[name='previous']").addEventListener('click',mainAction)
        document.querySelector("input[name='next']").addEventListener('click',mainAction)

        function mainAction(){
            if($('select option:selected').val() == 'a' || $('select option:selected').val() == 'b'){
                //do ur stuff
            }else{
                alert('Please select A or B');
            }
        }
```